# Verify value of property object inside Array

Tags: javascript, angularjs, lodash

I have the following array:

```
arrayObject = [
    { type: "one" },
    { type: "two" },
    { type: "other" },
];
```

And I also have the following array with values:

```
types = [
    "one",
    "other"
];
```

What I need is to verify if these two values exist, if they do not exist I must prevent them from advancing in a flow, currently what I am doing is:

```
arrayObject.filter(object => types.includes(object.type))
```

And this code returns me when none exists, but also returns me when one or the other exists, however what I need is to know if those two exist or not, it does not work for me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `every`

```
if (types.every(t => arrayObject.findIndex(a => a.type === t) > -1))
```

Comment: Excellent, it worked !!, just pass the time frame as correct!

Answer (score 1):

You could also use `Array.from` with `Array.every` and `Array.includes`:

```js
const arrayObject = [{ type: "one" }, { type: "two" }, { type: "other" }];
const types = ["one", "other"];

const result = types.every(t => Array.from(arrayObject, x=> x.type).includes(t))

console.log(result)
```

You could also use `Array.some` for more concise solution:

```js
const arrayObject = [{ type: "one" }, { type: "two" }, { type: "other" }];
const types = ["one", "other"];

const result = types.every(t => arrayObject.some(x => x.type === t))

console.log(result)
```

And since you have `lodash` tag:

```js
const arrayObject = [{ type: "one" }, { type: "two" }, { type: "other" }];
const types = ["one", "other"];

const result = _.every(types, x => _.some(arrayObject, {type: x}))

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.10/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Pluck the `type` from the `arrayObject` using `_.map()`. Use `_.intersection()`, and compare the results length to the length of the `types` array:

```js
const arrayObject = [{"type":"one"},{"type":"two"},{"type":"other"}];

const types = ["one","other"];

const result = _.eq(
  _.intersection(types, _.map(arrayObject, 'type')).length
, types.length);

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>
```